# Find previous fork point after branch rebase

Tags: git

I had a respository as

```
  A -- B -- C -- D    (master)
       \
         E -- F -- G  (feature)
              \
                ---H  (subfeature)
```

And ran `git rebase master feature` resulting in

```
                    --E'--F'--G'  (feature)
                  /
  A -- B -- C -- D                (master)
              \
                ---E--F--H        (subfeature)
```

After I made this mess I would like to now rebase subfeature to something like

```
  A -- B -- C -- D                  (master)
                  \
                   E' -- F' -- G'   (feature)
                        \
                          ---H"     (subfeature)
```

I suppose if I could find out the new commit for `F'` I could try to rebase onto that right?

Comment: `cherry-pick` accepts range of commits. 
If you are able to find F', then you can cherry pick those commits

Comment: @UtsavPatel, you have to add *sequential*, otherwise you have to add each commit separately to the list.

Comment: Use `git reflog` to find previous state of master and reset it hard to it. Then go again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your branch diagram for the state of things after the rebase is incorrect, and it should look like this instead:

```
feature:                 E' -- F' -- G'
                        /
master: A -- B -- C -- D
              \
subfeature:    E -- F -- H
```

Note that rebasing the `feature` branch should not affect the `subfeature` branch, which should still have the same chain of commits going back to the `B` commit in `master`.

If you want the sub feature's HEAD `H` commit to sit on top of the `F'` commit in the rebased `feature` branch, you may use `git rebase --onto`:

```
git checkout subfeature
git rebase --onto F' F
```

The second command says to rebase the `subfeature` branch such that the commit whose parent is now `F` sits on top of a new base `F'` commit.

Comment: thanks a lot I was missing F in this last comment! (Also fixed the question thanks)